# "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm" error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, connectivity

The full error message is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Context information:

- .Net console application written in C# running on windows 2016 server standard for testing the connectivity to a SQL Server 2008R2 database installed on Windows 2008r2.

The connection string pattern is: `$"Server='{server}'; Database='{db}'; UID='<sqllogin>'; PWD='<pwd>'"`

The app simply executes:

```
private static void TestConnection(string connectionString)
{
  var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  var msg = connectionString.Substring(0, connectionString.IndexOf("PWD"));
  try
  {
    cn.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The connection to {0} SUCCEEDED!", msg);
    cn.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("The connection to {0} FAILED!", msg);
    Console.WriteLine(ex);

  }
}
```

I enabled TLS 1.2 on the SQL server box with these settings and I rebooted it.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

I still get the error. I didn't want to touch the client registry settings.

Any other ideas?

Now that I think of it, on my dev windows 2016 server I never had any connectivity issues to SQL Server 2018R2 in SSMS or in Toad for SQL Server (which is implemented in C#).

Thanks

Comment: Is 2008 R2 >= SP3, v10.50.6542, with [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=3144114&kbln=en-us)? ([I blogged about this here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/tls-1-2-support-read-first).) Or maybe you could consider a supported version of the product?

Comment: It's 10.50.6000.34. Thanks for the link! We are in the process of upgrading to sql server 2017.

Comment: I found this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Yeah TLS 1.2 won't work on 10.50.6000.34, you're going to have to apply some updates (or accelerate the upgrade).